# Redirect all requests for a subfolder to the subfolders index.php with Apaches .htaccess and/or httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All I want to do is the following:

User attempts to connect to :
http://mydomain/invites/XYZ123456
or
http://mydomain/invites/FOOFOOBLAHBLAH
or
etc ...

**It must work** for **any URL that is entered after /invites** needs to display the same /invites/index.php

I want the webserver to always show /invites/index.php

I can't seem to get this to work...

I have tried to setup the .htaccess and place directly inside the folder (/my/WebServer/www/invites... which is http://localhost/invites/)

Note: I have made sure that I have loaded the 'rewrite_module' inside the apache httpd.conf

```
#.htaccess (located in /my/WebServer/www/invites)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule . index.php [R=302,L]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you allow htaccess to be executed (`AllowOverride` set to `All`) ? Do you have an htaccess in `www` with rules that could interfere ? Do you have other rules in `invites/.htaccess` ? Do you use a framework or something similar ?

Comment: Thanks Justin. That was the problem! I forgot to make sure this was set to 'All'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **AllowOverride** set to **All** inside the *httpd.conf* to enable the usage of the *.htaccess* file within the (for this example /www/invites directory).

Also make sure you have loaded the **rewrite_module** (*mod_rewrite.so*)

Hope this can help anyone who may run across this post:
I ended up using the following configuration parameters inside my .htaccess

```
# /www/invites/.htaccess
# Internal redirection to index.php for nonexistent URLs.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /invites/index.php [L,QSA]
```